# Deleted file not in recycle bin / Recovery options

Tags: windows, recycle-bin

I deleted some files from a different user account.  I don't see the files in either recycling bin.  When I right click on the recycle bin, I don't see the option to automatically remove files when deleted, so I don't know why the files aren't showing up.  One is a very large Virtualbox VM file.

To recover the data, is there a way to download and run something like Recuva when the USB drives aren't enabled and want to avoid downloading the software to the hard drive?

Comment: The file was to large, the confirmation message, indicated it was a permanent deletion.  If this was from a USB drive that also is normally a action that cannot be reversed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try and download Recuva to a different machine in the same network, and share its drive.

You say that USB drives are disabled. Do you have some other drive available? A CD-ROM drive, where a burned copy of Recuva (again downloaded from elsewhere) might fit? A SD-MMC slot perhaps? CompactFlash slot?

Otherwise, as a **last resort**, you might try and locate some old, large and not too useful file, *hope* that it will be found more convenient by the allocator, and shift-delete it after possibly mailing it to your own address for later restore.

You can risklessly do the same to your Internet cache, Temporary Files, and Downloads folder.

This *could* ensure that Recuva is downloaded to a newly freed area of the disk, without threatening the zone occupied by the Virtualbox VM file. But, of course, there is no guarantee.

Comment: @Iserni, great options I hadn't considered.  It turns Windows created a previous version that I could recover to by right clicking on the folder.  Any idea why the deleted files wouldn't show up in the Recycling Bin?